# How to sort eigenvalues (from minimum to maximum) and their corresponding eigenvectors?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, eigenvalues

When using NDEigensystem, the first eigenvalue corresponds to the first eigenvector, the second eigenvalue to the second eigenvectors, and so on. I would like to sort the eigenvalues from min to max, also so that the eigenvectors are also sorted accordingly. How can this be implemented?

in the code, I do not provide eigenvectors, because they are displayed as pictures

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]


{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + (-(1/x) + x^2)*u[x], 
  u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 10]

(*{{2.89816, 6.93897, -10.8147, 10.9162, 17.2964, 26.0667, 
  36.977, 49.9732, 65.0544, 
  82.2449}, {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 3.141592653589793}}, {
    5, 4225, 0, {41}, {3}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Indeterminate& , {}, {}, 
     False},...*)
```

You can see that Mathematica outputs the eigenvalues in an arbitrary order (the eigenvectors are arranged in the same order). Now I would like to sort the eigenvalues from minimum to maximum, but in such a way that their corresponding eigenvectors are sorted in the appropriate order.

If it's simply applied `Sort`, then the eigenvalues are sorted from minimum to maximum, but the eigenvectors are not sorted accordingly.

```
Sort /@ 
 NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + (-1/x + x^2)*u[x], 
  u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 10]

(*{{-10.8147, 2.89816, 6.93897, 10.9162, 17.2964, 26.0667, 
  36.977, 49.9732, 65.0544, 
  82.2449}, {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 3.141592653589793}}, {
    5, 4225, 0, {41}, {3}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Indeterminate& , {}, {}, 
     False},...*)
```

Comment: `Reverse /@  NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + (1/x + x^2)*u[x], 
  u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 10]`?

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, thanks! I edited the question, please take a look

Comment: Try: `ord = Ordering[vals];
{vals,funs}={vals[[ord]], funs[[ord]]}`

Comment: @Daniel Huber, thanks!

Comment: You could also look at `SortBy`

Answer (score 1):

```
{vals, funs} // Transpose // Sort // Transpose
```